# How to read a file and add its content to database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, file, insert

I have a text file called patientlist which looks like:

```
    george  19  180 75
    paul    20  182 84
    laura   21  176 73
```

What I want to do is to read this file and add the lines to a table in mysql database. I have written this code that reads the file:

```
    public static void patients() throws IOException{
    try {
        in= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("patientlist.txt")));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);}
    while((read = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(read);
     }
    }
```

"read" is the values from the file. I want to insert these values to my table in my database which has the parameters(name, age, height, weight) the 4 values on each line. I couldn't find out how to seperate the values on a line. Because I want george, paul and laura to be under the parameter of name at the database etc. so I can use select in future? Thanks for the help!

I have written some code like this can you check it out?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;
    Connection connection = DBConnection();
    try{
        String read=null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patientlist.txt")); 
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
            name = splited[0];
            age = splited[1];
            height = splited[2];
            weight = splited[3];
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);} 

    try {
        addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);               
        if (connection != null)
            try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore){}
        }

        catch (SQLException error) {System.out.println(error);}

    }
    public static void addpatient(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedstatement, String name, String age, String height, String weight) throws SQLException{
    preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into allpatients(name, age, height, weight) values(?,?,?,?)");
    preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
    preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
    preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate();

    }
```

Connection connection = DBConnection(); line creates the connection with database which has another method which I didn't write here. I think the problem is with my while loop, I think I should put a for loop too but my programming isn't very good please help, thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with the actual code? "While" is ok - unless each and every line includes a valid record. You may check if `splited.length == 4` before you access the values. Should throw an exception on empty lines now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
read.split("\\s+");
```

or, if your values are separated by `tab`,

```
read.split("\t");
```

With this code:

```
String s = "george  19  180 75";

String[]split = s.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(split[i]);
}
```

The output is:

```
george
19
180
75
```

Answer (score 0):

A patient list contains "patients" so I'd first create a class `Patient`. Then I'd create `Patient` instances for all lines in the file.

```
public class Patient {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private int height;
   private int weight;

   public Patient(String line) {
     String[] values = line.split("\\s+");
     name = values[0];
     age = values[1];
     height = values[2];
     weight = values[3];
   } 

   // not shown: getters/setters for the fields
}
```

Now, read the lines and create the objects

```
List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    patients.add(new Patient(line));
}
```

and use the list of patients to persist the data to the database. For each patient, prepare an insert statement and persist.

Comment: I didn't understand the List<Patient> part. Do you write that to your main method?