# loading a word2vec model into a Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, word2vec

I have a word2vec model stored in text file as

```
also -0.036738 -0.062687 -0.104392 -0.178325 0.010501 0.049380....
one -0.089568 -0.191083 0.038558 0.156755 -0.037399 -0.013798....
```

The size of the text file is more than 8GB.
I want to read this file into mysql database using the first word as key (in a column) and the rest of the line as another column. Is it possible to do so without reading each line and splitting it?

I went through some related questions but it didn't match what I want.

[How to read a file and add its content to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698384/how-to-read-a-file-and-add-its-content-to-database)

[read text file content and insert it into a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876594/read-text-file-content-and-insert-it-into-a-mysql-database)

Comment: were you successful at solving this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by:

1. making a simple for loop that iterates over the records on the model
2. aggregating about 100 records on an array
3. using mysql bulk insert feature to insert 100s of records at once

use a fast language like go if you can.

This thing you are trying to do, it's very possible, let me know if you need code for this.